# how to preserves special characters when sending them in php?

Tags: php

i need to send a string to a certain http. I am using php and at the server side their using aspx. my code is like this:

```
$post_data=$Fbid."]".$name."]".$first_name."]".$middle_name."]".$last_name."]".$link."]".$username."]".$workid."]".$workname."]".$position_id."]".$position_name."]".$position_date."]".$gender."]".$timezone;
```

the output will go like this :

```
data=597785639%26Anthony+G.+Helou%5DAnthony%5DG.%5DHelou%5Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fanthony.g.helou%5Danthony.g.helou%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D
```

it is changing the ] into %5D.

i used:

```
utf8_encode($post_data);
```

but i didn't work. Any help ??

Comment: This is URL encoded and it should decode itself before you read it from `$_POST`. Are you looking for `url_decode` and `url_encode`?

Comment: [What every web developer must know about URL encoding](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding)

Answer (score 1):

Its encrypt in URL, So while you are using it, u have to decrypt it.
So Use,

```
 $data = url_decode($data);
```